# Worker queue using RxJava

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I want to create worker queue using RxJava: I have a single thread doing some work, and I want to guarantee that no other job will be executed until we have finished/failed the current job.

My solution is simply to block the observable and wait for the result:

```
fun foo() : Observable<Foo> {
    return Observable.unsafeCreate { subscriber ->
        handlerThread.post {
            val answer = object.performSomeJob(whatever)
                    .flatMap { object.performAnotherJob(whatever) }
                    .flatMap { object.performLastJob(whatever) }
                    .blockingFirst()
            subscriber.onNext(answer)
            subscriber.onComplete()
        }
    }
}
```

You may argue that there is no need to use RxJava since everything's synchronous. That's true for this particular method, but:

1. I want to avoid 'callback hell': there are three methods, each of which is taking callback and I use RxJava to chain them
2. I use Rx further on in the caller method.

I know that `blocking` is generally considered as an anti-pattern, so can I do better in my case?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `concat` to perform work sequentially on some thread:

```
fun foo(): Observable<Foo> {
    return performSomeJob(whatever)
        .concatMap { performAnotherJob(whatever) }
        .concatMap { performLastJob(whatever) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule all your work on one single-threaded [`Scheduler`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Scheduler.html) such as

> ```
> @NonNull
> public static Scheduler single()
> ```
>
> Returns a default, shared, single-thread-backed Scheduler instance for work requiring strongly-sequential execution on the same background thread.

```
fun foo(): Observable<Foo> =
    Observable.fromCallable { object.performSomeJob(whatever) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .flatMap { object.performAnotherJob(whatever) }
        .flatMap { object.performLastJob(whatever) }
```

Comment: How do you make sure, that performAnotherJob Observerable will be called from calling thread? It could be that performAnotherJob is subscribeOn another thread. Furthermore maxConcurrency should be 1 for flatMap.

Comment: @HansWurst Assuming `performAnotherJob` and `performLastJob` do not change threads themselves, they will be observed on `Schedulers.single()`. If they do something more complex, that's under their control, not ours. Regardless of how many subscribers `maxConcurrency` allows, only a single task can be running on `Schedulers.observable()` at a time.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that a job would change thread and call observable from another thread. Unfortunately, I do not have any control over that code.

Comment: @ephemient, your example will not work. Please have a look at this code: https://gist.github.com/SergejIsbrecht/6a57c902e8b5319ee18af17b84e802ba . If you add .flatMap(integer -> create(integer), 1), than it will work.

Comment: @HansWurst It works in the example but still fails in that multiple `foo()` may still multiple tasks occurring at once. If the jobs switch threads there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Actually there is a solutions. Just look at @yosriz answer. Either use .concatMap(integer -> create(integer)) oder flatMap with maxConcurrency 1 overload.

Comment: As far as I can see @yosriz's solution is makes sure all operations are processed sequentially; what I want to achieve is atomicity: no other call to foo() should be executed until previous is completed (or failed).